# MongoDB installer with SSL and without SSL

Tags: mongodb, ssl, https

To install Mongo DB I can see two versions of installer one with SSL & other as without SSL.

https://www.mongodb.com/download-center?jmp=nav#community

My question is if I download with SSL installer & do not configure SSL then doesn't it same as without SSL installer. What is the need of without SSL installer at first place? Is there anything specific feature which comes in Without SSL installer?

I use Monggo DB in my application but not sure which one I should recommend to my customers as I have mix set of customers who want with/without SSL.

Atul

Comment: This question isn't really [on-topic as a programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for StackOverflow; it's really more of a usability question. For simplicity I think it makes sense to recommend all your users download the default version (with TLS/SSL support) so they have the option of configuring TLS/SSL if needed and can connect to third party services that require network encryption (eg. MongoDB Atlas).

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the SSL-included version running without SSL enabled, and the SSL-excluded version, is that the version without SSL does not have the [SSL libraries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl/) even present. If you are concerned about security flaws in OpenSSL, for example, then maybe you should use the version compiled without SSL.

Comment: ok - then it means if I am not installing SSL then I should be using "SSL-excluded version" instead of "SSL-included version" running without SSL enabled - right ?

Comment: Possibly; though to be honest, I suspect that you could just install the SSL-enabled version and, as long as you have other good security in place, it'd be fine.